# How can I use Three20 to create a dynamic TTThumbsViewController that feeds from a website directory?

Tags: xcode, ios, three20, gallery, photo

I'm pretty new to the iPhone developing scene, and I am designing an app for a high school band program.  Part of the app needs to be an image gallery that retrieves photos from a directory on the band's website and lists them in the thumbnail view.  I can't figure out how to create a thumsview that isn't directly linked to specific pictures.

I currently have this setup to work with a UIWebView that points to a PHP photo album designed to look like the iPhone Photo Album.  This method works, but it is not ideal, and the navigation is obviously a bit less than what would be expected.

Is Three20 the right tool for this job?  If not, what should I be using?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to set it up much like it's set up in `PhotoTest1Controller`. Here's a snippet of what's there...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.photoSource = [[[MockPhotoSource alloc]
        initWithType:MockPhotoSourceNormal
               title:@"Flickr Photos"
              photos:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[[MockPhoto alloc]
                                   initWithURL:@"http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3099/3164979221_6c0e583f7d.jpg?v=0"
                                      smallURL:@"http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3099/3164979221_6c0e583f7d_t.jpg"
                                          size:CGSizeMake(320, 480)] autorelease],
                                               [[[MockPhoto alloc]
                                   initWithURL:@"http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3099/3164979221_6c0e583f7d.jpg?v=0"
                                      smallURL:@"http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3099/3164979221_6c0e583f7d_t.jpg"
                                          size:CGSizeMake(320, 480)] autorelease],
                                               nil],

             photos2:nil] autorelease];
}
```

(I might be missing some brackets, but you get the gist)

Once you get a list of photos from your directory, you create an `NSArray` that contains a list of (in this case) `MockPhoto`s and replace the `photos` array with this created one.

As for whether this is the right library for it, I'd say yes... it's been awesome to work with in my apps.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I did manage to understand how to "hard code" a list of pictures into Three20 with the code you cited, but what I'm looking for is a way to list all of the photos in a directory that has its contents changed often. I need to figure out how to make the album automatically show the new pictures that are added, and remove pictures that have been deleted. Thanks for your reply, but unless I'm misunderstanding (more than a strong chance of that happening), what you have pointed to wont do what I need.